# How to find out what caused the coverage drop in simplecov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simplecov

We are using [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) as our code coverage tool and it's great. One thing that would make it even better would be an output saying which file changes caused the drop in the coverage.

One possible way would be to store .resultset.json files and compare them with the newest results. Any other ideas? Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: how I'm now doing is using spreadsheet functions, and it sucks. seems this requirement will be a good idea to a new ruby gem.